# Is it possible to create navive Mac OS install file (disk image .dmg) from Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, dmg, sles

Is it possible to create .dmg package from SLES 11 Linux?

The idea is - copy native Mac JRE to Linux, copy JARs (crossplatform files), copy application icon to Linux, and use some bash script to create a .dmg file which can be installed later on Mac OS X?

Also, make a note that SLES is os390 64 bit, if it matters.

@Thomas, my question is not duplicate. Answer on linked question is about (a) Windows, (b) commercial tools. The Linux solution proposed there creates invalid .dmg

Comment: @Thomas, kenorb, Piyush, Andrew Arnold, m0nhawk , I disagree with your lock of my question. Again, the linked question does not provide *clear* answer to my specific situation: SLES 11 on os390 platform.